# Python Selenium preceding:: to find element error

Tags: python, selenium

I'd like to

1. find all titles in the link with '2021' in it
2. get all links, titles and dates

I use:

```
all_links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'2021'/preceding::a)]")]
titles = [title.text for title in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'2021') ]")]
dates = [date.text for date in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'2021')]/following::td/span")]
    for link, title, date in zip(links, titles, dates):
...
```

ERROR:SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': Type conversion failed while evaluating the expression.
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)

link:http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/bond/notice/index.html

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi did you want the a tag that has attachformat to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `links`, please try with this xpath:

```
//span[@class='pull-left ellipsis title-text' and contains(text(), '2021')]
```

From the above xpath you can achieve `href` with **`//parent::a`** and `date` with **`//ancestor::td//following-sibling::td`**.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left ellipsis title-text' and contains(text(), '2021')]")))
titles = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left ellipsis title-text' and contains(text(), '2021')]//parent::a")))
dates = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left ellipsis title-text' and contains(text(), '2021')]//ancestor::td//following-sibling::td")))

for link, title, date in zip(links, titles, dates):
    print(link.text)
    print(title.get_attribute("href"))
    print(date.text)
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for your help! it works fine. may I ask in ```dates```, why do not put ```ancestor::td//following-sibling::td/span``` with span in td? as the date text is in span; besides, may I ask is ```ancestor``` select the first parent's parent? sorry I have not use ancestor  before...thanks!

Comment: @Joyce And for `ancestor`, it doesn't select the first parent, but all (parent, grandparent, etc.). In this case, there is only one `td` from each `links` (current node). See more here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp, mays help you.

Comment: thank you for your help! but this time I run the codes,  it only returns ```<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3bdf720c1e64cee11b97b2a704e9f65c", element="736f0f72-1a97-43d4-bb03-af10dadac09d")>```, I only put ```while true``` outside the codes

Comment: @Joyce It prints the `WebElement` only. Have you called `.text` or `.get_attribute("href")`?

Comment: Oh right, got it, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Joyce I don't put `/span` in `ancestor::td//following-sibling::td` because it's return same value, except after `/td` there is other text you don't want. Glad it worked, if your issue is solved, please mark this answer or other answer by clicking the `√` icon, so this thread isn't left unanswered, and feel free to upvote.

Comment: No problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent tag with a span that contains a text we do the following.

```
all_links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'2021')]]")]
print(all_links)
```

Use waits

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
all_links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'2021')]]")))]
print(all_links)
```

Outputs

```
['http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?5bcbb736-4f52-46a0-9bd1-7ed240cb6ebc', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?f9aab31e-b0dc-4bda-84b3-61c099a8e341', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?e79765a9-e342-4798-93a0-6b53c186329d', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?c87ecd93-c7b6-433b-a1ce-567e1b0da785', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?c063e776-c96e-4ee0-aff2-a1fa8f3d14ed', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?1f7200a6-52f6-425b-b4bf-e87c1d4cbbba', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?de0aae6d-363a-49f6-af39-8976bb04d6e6', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?ca829df1-0ff5-4e34-9a5c-f67113e74c81', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?4e490995-6805-4bc2-bec1-e9417d7bf0dc', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?f1f000c0-1aa0-48c8-8925-c5f6e37447ed', 'http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/bulletinDetail/index.html?affce6c9-2a54-4dca-b2e9-37ed3d6acfd8']
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: hello, but still got SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': Type conversion failed while evaluating the expression.error, does```a[@attachformat]```mean all a tags with attchmentformat tags in it?

Comment: This means get all a tag with attachformat whose child has that text.

Comment: Your zip is improper as well.

Comment: Hello, for dates, May i ask if ```dates=[date.text for date in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'2021')]]//following-sibling::td//span")))]``` is correct?

Comment: dates=[date.text for date in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'2021')]]/following::td[1]/span")))]

Answer (score 1):

the Table is created after page loaded so you have to wait, and it better to loop through the rows or `tr`

```
# wait for the table, max 10 seconds
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table tbody tr'))) 

rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.table tbody tr')
for row in rows:
    title = row.find_element_by_css_selector('.title-text').text
    if '2021' not in title:
        continue
    link = row.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    date = row.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-time').text
    print(title, link, date)
```

Comment: Hi thanks!, it works fine! may I ask what does```('.table tbody tr')``` mean?all thes tags or?

Comment: its CSS selector, it select table with class `table` or element `<table class="table">` then `tbody` and `tr`, it similiar with xpath `//table/tbody/tr`